# Remove a directory name from URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am having URL as blow:

http://www.example.com/joi-videos/user_videos/rakesh/index.php

I want to remove "user_videos" from url and URL should be like like below:
http://www.example.com/rakesh/index.php

Please help me with this:

I am writing below code but its not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user_videos/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ user_videos/$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^joi-videos/(.*)/?$ /joi-videos/user_videos/rakesh/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: using this it is fourcefully foing to http://www.example.com/joi-videos/user_videos/rakesh/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule inside **`/joi-videos/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /joi-videos/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!user_videos/).*)$ user_videos/$1 [NC,L]
```